# Plumbing: Bypass Pull Stop Box by converting its 3/8" compression outlet to a 3/8" iron pipe

Tags: plumbing, connectors

Situation:

My kitchen sink's shut off valve is this Pull Stop Box Product [specs pdf](https://s22970.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/PullStop_SpecS_10122020.pdf).

I wanted to install a reverse osmosis system [specs pdf](http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/854961005846_install.pdf), and wanted to intercept the main water supply from the Pull Stop Box.

Consider the standard way of installing these water filtration systems (p. 11 in the spec):

[image: RO system install diagram with shutoff valve on a water supply line, connecting to the system's needle valve, and then a riser, etc.]

Instead of removing the Pull Stop Box, I was thinking of:

1. open up the pull stop box plastic, and access its 3/8" compression outlet
2. find a female compression adapter that connects to the above compression outlet, and converts into a female iron pipe (3/8").
3. connect a solid, long, 3/8" iron nipple
4. put an angled shut off valve on the nipple, and follow the rest of the standard install for the RO system.

Now, I'm having a whole lot of trouble with number 2 -- I can't seem to find an adapter that could connect a stubby compression outlet to female iron pipe.

Am I going the wrong way (well, I bet removing the Pull Stop Box entirely would be the better way, but just curious)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: use brass instead of iron. don't mix dissimilar metals.

2: go to a plumbing supply store they have 10 times the product range of a big hardware store. the will have an adaptor that will convert the compression end to NPT  then you can fit your regular shut-off - or just fit an elbow and connect reverse osmosis fork adaptor.

Comment: Just wanted to update for anyone else running into this issue. I stopped by a plumbing supply store and couldn't exactly find an adapter that did that. But I was able to order the pull stop box tee adaptor from a nearby plumbing supply and was golden: Tee Adaptor, Female 3/8" Comp x 2" x Male 3/8" Comp ITEM #: P-06735